# opencart big proplem for me ,

Tags: php, opencart

i have a problem with a site that i develop 
this is the site 
http://jumairah.co/admin/

the error is

```
  Call to a member function isLogged() on a non-object
```

i tried to re upload all files and the problem still exist ;
the problem exist when i move the site from here 
http://projects.eng-mostafa.com/designs/opencart/admin

any one help please

---

this is the line of the problem

```
    if ($this->customer->isLogged()) {
        $customer_group_id = $this->customer->getCustomerGroupId();
    } else {
        $customer_group_id = $this->config->get('config_customer_group_id');
    }
```

and the function of islogged 
in that path 
/public_html/system/library/customer.php

and this is the function

```
public function isLogged() {
    return $this->customer_id;
}
```

---

Comment: post the contents of the isLogged() function AND also post the lines the error is erroring for. This is not enough info to help otherwise.

Comment: i added the lines of the problem

Comment: Then what is `customer`?

Comment: customer on this file /public_html/system/library/customer.php

Comment: Your `config.php` files are wrong (at least the one in `/admin`), they should not have the same code (as it seems). Backup your store (database and files), do a clean installation and restore/upload everything (except for `/config.php` and `/admin/config.php` files created by the installation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution after extra trials ,

i make a new database and make a fresh install for opencart , 
this step will create the config and check for all 777 folder

after finish the fresh install , i modified the config and put the old database data in it ,